# Getting data from event args in ListViewItem click handler

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, eventargs

So i have a some ListView populated with data.  And i have item click-handler. It looks so

```
var listview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myList);
listview .ItemClick += OnItemClick;

// populating listview items
MyModel[] someDataArray = GetData();
listview .Adapter = new MyAdapter(this, someDataArray );

....

protected async void OnItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{        
    // here i would like to perfom some actions with instance of MyModel 
    // associated with current ListView's Item
}
```

I wanna get the instance of MyModel associated with ListView's Item in OnItemClick event handler but i dont know how i can get this model in this event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Position` property on the `ItemClickEventArgs`. So,

```
MyModel model = someDataArray[e.Position];
```